# Нужна ли запятая перед "да"? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Ты да я.** Нужна ли запятая перед "да"?

Answer (score 4):

[ДА](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/182/%D0%B4%D0%B0)
1. Союз. Одиночный союз **да**, употребленный в значении соединительного союза **и**, не требует до и после себя знаков препинания, если он соединяет однородные члены предложения.

**Ты да я** [да = и].

*Мы с тобой, **ты да я** —

Берега реки одной.*

Пословицы: Щи **да** каша — пища наша. День **да** ночь — сутки прочь.

Алексей. (…) *Только прости и люби, люби всегда. И пусть о том никто не знает. Только ты да я, **ты да я**...*
[Д. С. Мережковский. Царевич Алексей](https://books.google.ee/books?id=H5e3yFttujUC&pg=PT79&lpg=PT79&dq=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=unJI0OJBf_&sig=zAztqOcF8gfrlq1SvxWCRtHIuQk&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIrv3wudveAhXEjCwKHdSlAec4KBDoATAEegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D1%8F&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то говоря, запятая не нужна (см. ответ Риммы), но не исключаю, что в каком-то, очень специфическом контексте это "да" может быть употреблено в присоединительном смысле, и тогда появится запятая.